# Add indicator to top and bottom 10%

Tags: oracle, outliers, case-statement

I'm trying to capture the average of FIRST_CONTACT_CAL_DAYS but what I would like to do is create an indicator for the top and bottom 10% of values so I can exclude those (outliers) from my average calculation.

Not sure how to go about do this, any thoughts?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        TO_CHAR(A.FIRST_ASSGN_DT,'DAY') AS DAY_NUMBER,
        A.FIRST_ASSGN_DT,
        A.FIRST_CONTACT_DT,
        TO_CHAR(A.FIRST_CONTACT_DT,'DAY') AS DAY_NUMBER2,                   
        A.FIRST_CONTACT_DT AS FIRST_PHONE_CONTACT, 
        A.ID,
        ABS(TO_DATE(A.FIRST_CONTACT_DT, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - TO_DATE(A.FIRST_ASSGN_DT, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) AS FIRST_CONTACT_CAL_DAYS,   

        FROM HIST A
          LEFT JOIN  CONTACTS D ON A.ID = D.ID 

        WHERE 1=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this. Please adapt to your situation.

I assume you may have more than one "group" or "partition" and you need to compute the average for each group separately, after throwing out the outliers in each partition. (An alternative, which can be easily accommodated by adapting the query below, is to throw out the outliers at the global level, and only then to group and take the average for each group.)

If you don't have any groups, and everything is one big pile of data, it's even easier - you don't need GROUP BY and PARTITION BY.

Then: the function NTILE assigns a bucket number, in this example between 1 and 10, to each row, based on where they fall (first decile, i.e. first 10%, next decile, ... all the way to the last decile). I do this in a subquery. Then in the outer query just filter out the first and last bucket before you group by and you compute the average.

For testing purposes I create three groups with 10,000 random numbers each in a WITH clause - no need to spend any time on that portion of the code, since it is not part of the solution (the SQL code to solve your problem) - it's just a dirty trick to create test data on the fly.

```
with
     inputs ( grp, val ) as (
       select     ceil(level/10000), dbms_random.value(0, 150)
       from       dual
       connect by level <= 30000
     )
select   grp, avg(val) as avg_val
from     (
           select grp, val, ntile(10) over (partition by grp order by val) as bkt
           from   inputs
         )
where    bkt between 2 and 9
group by grp
;

GRP                  AVG_VAL
---  -----------------------
  1 75.021614866547043734458
  2 74.286117923344418598032
  3 75.437412573353736953791
```